# data-role="button" style is not applied on js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

On _Layout page inside header I have div which is initially hidden on page load.

```
 <div data-role="header">
    <div id="myDiv" data-role="button"></div>
 </div>

...
$(document).bind("pageinit", function () {
     $("div#myDiv").hide();
});
```

somewhere on other page onclick action is wired to js function which adds text content to myDiv, and after that I'm showing myDiv like

```
<script>
   ...
      var textToAppend = "some text";
      $("div#myDiv").html(textToAppend);  
      $("div#myDiv").show();
   ...
</script>
```

Div is shown with text but visually without expected style (data-role="button). In firebug div has data-role button correctly set but visually not.

Comment: What does the css look like for data-role="button" ?

Comment: when testing, css is correctly applied before calling js function. Standard css class for button in jquery mobile.

Comment: please check your question, i think you have somthing. it is working properly.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with showing/hiding, but rather changing the text. See the following jsfiddle that just updates the text - http://jsfiddle.net/BQMTP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the data-role is setting up with some spans, the rendered code looks like:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
      <span class="ui-btn-text">some test</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Your current code will overwrite the spans and the formatting gets messed up. You must replace the text of the inner span - use the following to update the text:

```
$("div#myDiv .ui-btn-text").text(textToAppend);
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BQMTP/2/

Answer (score 1):

When you change elements content dynamically you should recreate the element so jquery mobile's enhanced markup is applied. In this case:

```
$("div#myDiv").html(textToAppend).button();
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gfg/Z9xvd/

I would recommend this approach because it doesn't rely on html markup, which has changed a lot in version 1.4 of jQuery mobile.

For example, the following html: `<input id="btnShow" type="submit" value="show">` will be:

**jQuery mobile 1.3.2**

```
<div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" data-disabled="false" class="ui-submit ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">show</span>
    </span>
    <input id="btnShow" type="submit" value="show" class="ui-btn-hidden" data-disabled="false">
</div>
```

**jQuery mobile 1.4.2**

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    show
    <input id="btnShow" type="submit" value="show">
</div>
```